# is concourse compatible with swarm mode in Docker?

Tags: concourse

Would you know if concourse is compatible with swarm mode?
I am able to spin up concourse web but not the worker when using swarm mode.
If docker-compose is used with the flag set to privileged: true, then it works.
Bug Report

```
Concourse version: fly-version is 3.2.1
fly -version
3.2.1
Deployment type (BOSH/Docker/binary):Docker
Infrastructure/IaaS:
Browser (if applicable):
Did this used to work?yes with docker-compose but not with in a docker swarm mode
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | Exit trace for group:
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | garden exited with error: Exit trace for group:
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | garden-runc exited with error: bulk starter: setting up default chains: iptables: setup-global-chains: + set -o nounset
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + set -o errexit
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + shopt -s nullglob
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + filter_input_chain=w--input
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + filter_forward_chain=w--forward
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + filter_default_chain=w--default
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + filter_instance_prefix=w--instance-
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + nat_prerouting_chain=w--prerouting
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + nat_postrouting_chain=w--postrouting
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + nat_instance_prefix=w--instance-
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + iptables_bin=/worker-state/3.2.1/assets/iptables/sbin/iptables
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + case "${ACTION}" in
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + setup_filter
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + teardown_filter
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + teardown_deprecated_rules
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | ++ /worker-state/3.2.1/assets/iptables/sbin/iptables -w -S INPUT
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + rules=
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + true
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + echo ''
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + grep ' -j garden-dispatch'
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + sed -e s/-A/-D/ -e 's/\s+$//'
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + xargs --no-run-if-empty --max-lines=1 /worker-state/3.2.1/assets/iptables/sbin/iptables -w
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | ++ /worker-state/3.2.1/assets/iptables/sbin/iptables -w -S FORWARD
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + rules=
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + true
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + echo ''
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + grep ' -j garden-dispatch'
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + sed -e s/-A/-D/ -e 's/\s+$//'
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + xargs --no-run-if-empty --max-lines=1 /worker-state/3.2.1/assets/iptables/sbin/iptables -w
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + /worker-state/3.2.1/assets/iptables/sbin/iptables -w -F garden-dispatch
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + true
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + /worker-state/3.2.1/assets/iptables/sbin/iptables -w -X garden-dispatch
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + true
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | ++ /worker-state/3.2.1/assets/iptables/sbin/iptables -w -S w--forward
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + rules=
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + true
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + echo ''
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + grep '-g w--instance-'
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + sed -e s/-A/-D/ -e 's/\s+$//'
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + xargs --no-run-if-empty --max-lines=1 /worker-state/3.2.1/assets/iptables/sbin/iptables -w
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | ++ /worker-state/3.2.1/assets/iptables/sbin/iptables -w -S
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + rules=
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + true
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + echo ''
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + grep '^-A w--instance-'
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + sed -e s/-A/-D/ -e 's/\s+$//'
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + xargs --no-run-if-empty --max-lines=1 /worker-state/3.2.1/assets/iptables/sbin/iptables -w
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | ++ /worker-state/3.2.1/assets/iptables/sbin/iptables -w -S
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + rules=
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + true
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + echo ''
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + grep '^-N w--instance-'
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + sed -e s/-N/-X/ -e 's/\s+$//'
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + xargs --no-run-if-empty --max-lines=1 /worker-state/3.2.1/assets/iptables/sbin/iptables -w
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | ++ /worker-state/3.2.1/assets/iptables/sbin/iptables -w -S FORWARD
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + rules=
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + true
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + echo ''
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + grep ' -j w--forward'
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + sed -e s/-A/-D/ -e 's/\s+$//'
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + xargs --no-run-if-empty --max-lines=1 /worker-state/3.2.1/assets/iptables/sbin/iptables -w
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + /worker-state/3.2.1/assets/iptables/sbin/iptables -w -F w--forward
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + true
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + /worker-state/3.2.1/assets/iptables/sbin/iptables -w -F w--default
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + true
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | ++ /worker-state/3.2.1/assets/iptables/sbin/iptables -w -S INPUT
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + rules=
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + true
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + echo ''
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + grep ' -j w--input'
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + sed -e s/-A/-D/ -e 's/\s+$//'
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + xargs --no-run-if-empty --max-lines=1 /worker-state/3.2.1/assets/iptables/sbin/iptables -w
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + /worker-state/3.2.1/assets/iptables/sbin/iptables -w -F w--input
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + true
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + /worker-state/3.2.1/assets/iptables/sbin/iptables -w -X w--input
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + true
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | ++ ip route show
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | ++ grep default
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | ++ cut '-d ' -f5
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | ++ head -1
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + default_interface=eth1
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + /worker-state/3.2.1/assets/iptables/sbin/iptables -w -N w--input
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | + /worker-state/3.2.1/assets/iptables/sbin/iptables -w -F w--input
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | iptables v1.4.21: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Permission denied (you must be root)
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora |
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | dns-proxy exited with nil
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora |
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | baggageclaim exited with nil
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora | beacon exited with error: failed to dial: failed to connect to TSA: dial tcp: lookup concourse-web on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host
ci_concourse-worker.1.sdwlru32wymn@node-ora |
```

Comment: This is also called out here as well in a more recent post to the concourse-docker repo: https://github.com/concourse/concourse-docker/issues/50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer at the moment of writing: No

Privileged mode is not available for services deployed in a swarm, but a feature that will allow you to get similar permissions is in the works.
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/32801